# Get warning after updating component in Navigator

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a container in my React Native app and and I use it like preload to show scene `Loading...` before I get data from server. So I dispatch an action to fetch user data and after that I update my state I try to push new component to `Navigator` but I've got an error:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

And I don't understand what is the best way to fix my problem.

So my container:

```
import myComponent from '../components'

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUser());
  }

  _navigate(component, type = 'Normal') {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component,
      type
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.isFetching) {
      this._navigate(myComponent);
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Loading...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
App.propTypes = {
  dispatch: React.PropTypes.func,
  isFetching: React.PropTypes.bool,
  user: React.PropTypes.string
};

export default connect((state) => ({
  isFetching: state.data.isFetching,
  data: state.data.user
}))(App);
```

My reducer:

```
const data = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        user: action.user
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't trigger anything that can `setState` inside the body of your `render` method. If you need to listen to incoming props, use `componentWillReceiveProps`

Remove this from `render()`:

```
if (!this.props.isFetching) {
  this._navigate(myComponent);
}
```

and add `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (!nextProps.isFetching) {
    this._navigate(myComponent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!